# создать новый экземпляр scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть приложение на angular, табы. При создании новой вкладки табов я передаю через директиву шаблон контента

```
return {
       restrict : 'E',
       templateUrl : 'tab-content.html'
}
```

Если я добавлю студентов в контенте, то, при добавлении следующей вкладки, студенты сохраняться, можно ли при создании новой вкладки передать изначальный `templateUrl : 'tab-content.html'` ? Пробовал изолировать скоуп - `scope : {}`, но тогда у меня вообще шаблон не передается.

[Пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/j1DOXVzq3l3uwKzkGfYa?p=preview).

Comment: Упрости пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy немного упростил, чтобы не потерять суть, tab-content.html смысловой нагрузки не несет, там просто контент что будет заполнять табы. В js думаю все дело именно в директиве, думаю даже в scope, тк данные с нее тянет, но вот в чем конкретно, не могу понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что нет разделения на вкладки.

Если посмотреть код:

1. $scope.students - общее для всех, непонятно. должен ли быть этот список общим. либо быть своим у каждой вкладки
2. gradeName - выводимый в заголовке вкладки и заполняемый в шаблоне, общий для всех.
3. $scope.selectedGrade - нигде не используется, фактически, присваивается ради присваивания.

Решений может быть несколько, на мой взгляд, самым простым было бы - создание переменной хранящей информацию о текущей вкладке, и при смене вкладки менять эту переменную.
Сейчас ее аналог выполняет `$scope.selectedGrade`, если использовать ее везде, где нужны данные конкретной вкладки. то проблемы бы не было.

Пример с сохранением выбранного объекта:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.addStudent = function() {
      $scope.selectedGrade.students.push({
        name: $scope.newName,
        gpa: $scope.newGpa
      });
      $scope.newName = '';
      $scope.newGpa = '';
    };


    // operations with tabs
    var addNewGrade = function() {
      var id = $scope.grades.length + 1;
      $scope.selectedGrade = {
        id: id,
        name: "Grade " + id,
        active: true,
        students: []
      };
      $scope.grades.push($scope.selectedGrade);
    };

    $scope.grades = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Grade 8A",
      active: true,
      students: [{
        name: 'Vasya Pupkin',
        gpa: '4.8'
      }, {
        name: 'Petia Vasechkin',
        gpa: '3.2'
      }]
    }];

    $scope.addGrade = function() {
      addNewGrade();
    };

    $scope.selectedGrade = $scope.grades[0];

    $scope.selectGrade = function(grade) {
      $scope.selectedGrade = grade;
    }
  }
]);

app.directive('newGrades', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'tab-content.html'
  }
})
```

```css
.btn-xs {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 23px;
}
.tab-content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.tab-content input {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.remove:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-content .add input {
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
}
.tab-content .add .gpa-width {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active" ng-repeat="grade in grades" ng-click="selectGrade(grade)" ng-class="{'active':selectedGrade == grade}">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{grade.id}}">{{grade.name}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <span class="remove" ng-click="deleteGrade($index)"> x</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="addGrade()">+</a>
        </ul>
        <new-grades></new-grades>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tab-content.html">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="{{selectedGrade.id}}" class="tab-panel">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label for="grade">GRADE</label>
              <input type="text" id="grade" ng-model="selectedGrade.name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <h4>NAME</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3">
              <h4>GPA</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row" ng-repeat="student in selectedGrade.students">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <h4>{{student.name}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <h4>{{student.gpa}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <span class="remove" ng-click="removeItem(student)">x</span>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row add">
            <form class="form-inline ng-valid ng-dirty ng-submitted" ng-submit="addStudent()">
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="newName" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
                <input class="gpa-width" type="text" ng-model="newGpa" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">add</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за такое подробное разьяснение! теперь я вижу свою ошибку. поэтому и связывание не помогало, да и безсмысленно оно тут было.